# how to receive values from openzeppelin royaltyInfo function

Tags: solidity, tokens, openzeppelin-contracts, alchemy

trying to implement like this

```
uint[2] memory royalty = royaltyInfo(_tokenId, price);

payable(royalty[0]).transfer(royalty[1]);
```

but getting error

```
TypeError: Different number of components on the left hand side (1) than on the right hand side (2).
  --> contracts/NFTMarketplace.sol:98:9:
   |
98 |         uint[2] memory royalty = royaltyInfo(_tokenId, price);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


TypeError: Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256[2] memory.
  --> contracts/NFTMarketplace.sol:98:9:
   |
98 |         uint[2] memory royalty = royaltyInfo(_tokenId, price);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


TypeError: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "uint256" to "address payable".
   --> contracts/NFTMarketplace.sol:105:9:
    |
105 |         payable(royalty[0]).transfer(royalty[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to transfer funds to `royalty[0]` which should be a valid address rather than a uint256, as the third errors says.

From what I can tell, the `royaltyInfo` function should return the address to which the funds must be sent and the amount. If so, you need to update the return type of the `royaltyInfo` as following:

```
function royaltyInfo(
    uint256 _tokenId,
    uint256 price
) public returns (address recipient, uint256 amount) {
    address _recipient;
    uint256 _amount;
    
    // INSERT YOUR LOGIC HERE

    return (_recipient, _amount);
}
```

and get the address and amount like this:

```
(address recipient, uint256 amount) = royaltyInfo(tokenId, price);
```

then you can send the funds using the returned values:

```
payable(recipient).transfer(amount);
```